# Display Ads with iAd without Storyboard or Xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I have been trying to make a banner ad appear at the bottom of my App, without the use of storyboards or Xib files. Sadly this is not working out. I have tried following tutorials, and just not adding the Storyboard, to no avail. My project compiles fine but the Ad is not displayed at the bottom of the simulator, or anywhere for that matter. Here is a relevant sample of my viewcontroller.mm code:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    ADBannerView *_bannerView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:(_bannerView)];
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true;

}
```

The header imports , iAd.framework is included. The header also has this modified line `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>`

Comment: No one can help fix your code if you don't provide any details about what you are doing. Update your question with some relevant code.

Comment: No need to downvote, I didn't realize this question would be code related considering I was following a tutorial that was made for a storyboard. Post will be updated shortly.

Comment: Where's the code that actually creates the banner view?

Comment: This is all that the tutorial I followed had in it. Along with the storyboard with the iAd object on it.

Comment: How do you expect the banner to appear if you never create it? `_bannerView` will be `nil` until you do.

Comment: My apologies, I have never used the iAd framework. I am also newish to XCode development, could you point me towards a tutorial shows how to create it?

Comment: Read the "iAd Programming Guide" in Apple's docs. Always start with Apple's docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing `bannerView`, if you dont initialize it, like any other UI object you will not see anything. So initialize it first, then you add it to the view and also enable `canDisplayBannerAds` to prevent any errors.

```
@implementation ViewController{
ADBannerView *_bannerView; }

- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
 self.canDisplayBannerAds = true;
 //_bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)];

//Instead of giving the position when initializing, give the AdType
        bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];

//Then give the position
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

[self.view addSubview:(_bannerView)];

}
```

Like @Christophr said, also enable iAd fill rate on the iOS testing device.

That should work.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This did not appear to work, the ad still does not appear at the bottom. My Code is nearly identical to yours.

Comment: Are you showing up more Objects in this Controller? Maybe they are hidden, try to change the position of the banner. If this is not the problem try my updated answer.

Comment: I had a mistake, the min. height for a ADBannerView is 50, also change that.

Comment: Still not working, I changed position just to see what would happen and still nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79874/discussion-between-karlo-a-lopez-and-reborn).

Comment: The error was something very simple, it never showed up as an actual error but down in the output I noticed something about my root viewcontroller not being set. After resolving that your answer worked. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect, please consider choosing me as the best answer. By checking the green tick

Answer (score 0):

Import iAd framework, then in your viewcontroller, set self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

Also, check in your device/simulator settings - Settings > Developer > Fill Rate

Choose 100% if you want test ads to always succeed in loading.

Comment: That you for the Fill Rate tip. It didn't work, meaning it is most likely a code error. I will update my post with code.